# Error When deploying Experience Bundle to Related to Variations Folder on the Bundle

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, community, community-builder, experience-cloud

We are receiving the below error when we are trying to deploy the experience bundle on the community to different Org.

What Components we are deploying:

1. Experience Bundle
2. Profiles
3. We add few LWC and Aura Components which is used in Community.

Source & Target Orgs: Sandbox.

Deployment ERROR :

```
The value for targetId in Prop_Community1/variations/homeThemeNavigationMenu1ComponentProperties.json isn't valid. Check the value and try again.
```

When we are trying to see this metadata in Visual studio we don't have variations folder it self

[image: When we are trying to see this metadata in Visual studio we don't have variations folder it self]

Like to know why this error is coming???

Comment: Hello Vinod - Could you please share what have you attempted (for example if you are deploying the Experience Bundle alone) and more about your environment (if it is a scratch org, sandbox, etc)? This could help others to provide your more insights.

Comment: Details Updated!

Comment: Have you deployed the Site.com and Network components from a changeset into the target org first?

Comment: We are using copado for deployment we have added SiteDotCom in the same story and deploying and networks are not added

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me to this error message was to delete that file cause it was a deprecated one. At the same time the reference was at a deprecated page that I had removed from the org but not from my repo.